# What are the dependencies of Google Maps v2?

Tags: android, google-maps, dependencies

I am new to Android and want to embed [Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/) v2 to my application, but can anyone please tell me which dependencies should I install on phone or include to project?

Answer (score 15):

Include Gradle dependency:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
}
```

You may found [Gradle, please](http://gradleplease.appspot.com/) helpful. Also, check out [this page](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases) for Android APIs releases.

Comment: It will give you direct latest dependency of [google maps](http://gradleplease.appspot.com/#google-maps)

Comment: @PratikButani your link gives me `'com.google.maps:google-maps-services:0.9.1'`. Note: this is not the same library! If you read `google-maps-services` [page on Github](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-java) you'll see "The Java Client for Google Maps Services is designed for use in server applications. This library is not intended for use inside of an Android app".

Comment: Ohh I see. Can you tell me new version of `'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'` in **Gradle, please**

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have already read https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/ :-)

In short:

- you need to download and install the Google Play service lib via SDK manager
- create a project in Eclipse via "Create project from existing source code" and use the source code from "\android-sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib"
- add this project as dependency to your actual project via right click on your project -> properties -> android -> add project library
- add the permissions as described in the link mentioned above
- request an API key as pointed out in the link above as well
- add a SupportedMapFragment to your layout
- you need an active Google account on the device to will test your map (it will install the required dependencies on the device automatically then)

That's it :-)

Hope that helps....